# Back button restores unwanted previous page in Android on Xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin

I am developing an app that starts with a login page, called `LoginPage`.

Once logged in a different page is viewed, called `UserPage`.

Once `LoginPage` has been popped and `UserPage` has been pushed, I press the back button on the Android device, which takes me to the home screen.

Once at the home screen I reopen the app from the app manager (the little square button at the lower right side of the device) and the `LoginPage` reappears.

Why is that?

My code to pop the `LoginScreen` is as following:

```
Application.Current.MainPage = new UserPage();
await Navigation.PopToRootAsync(true);
```

**EDIT 1**
Main app method

```
    public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var navPage = new NavigationPage(new LoginPage());
        NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(navPage.CurrentPage, false);

        MainPage = navPage;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Once at the home screen I reopen the app from the app manager (the little square button at the lower right side of the device) and the LoginPage reappears.

According your code :

```
Application.Current.MainPage = new UserPage();
await Navigation.PopToRootAsync(true);
```

Pop up the login page and set the main page is `UserPage`. At this time your page stack only have the `UserPage`. When you click the back button. **The app has been killed by the system.**

**But android will keep app the shot cut at the app manager. When you click the shot cut in fact you are reopening your app. And your MainPage is `LoginPage` so you will see your `LoginPage` again.**

I have added the output message in the app init function:

**App Init:**

```
public App()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("ini app again");
    MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage());
}
```

**MainPage Init**

```
public MainPage()
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("init Mainpage again");
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

When I click the button pop up the mainpage and go to page1:

```
private async void bt1_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      Application.Current.MainPage = new Page1();
      await Navigation.PopToRootAsync(true);
}
```

Run you my code you will find when you click the back button you actually open the app again and it will show the mainpage again:

[image]

Comment: Yes that is what happens to my code as well. I don't want that. I'd like it to resume from where it stopped, not restart the app completely.

Comment: @vaid in the android platform if your page stack has only one page, And you click the back button the app will be killed. Because there will be no page to back.  If you what your app resume from where it stopped, please click the little squire icon at the right corner.

Comment: I see, so it is expected behavior from all apps?
I'm a little bit worried that it might confuse the users of the app if they need to re-login every time.

Comment: @vaid yes it is expected behavior from all apps.  But you can keep user login state by another way. Using `sharedpreferrence` is the normal method. This [link](http://www.skill-guru.com/blog/2011/01/17/data-storage-mechanisms-in-android/) will be helpful.

Comment: @vaid, So do you have any solution for it? like let back button function same as back to home, and next time start from the last place?

Answer (score 0):

Your application's main page does not have a navigation stack where it could store the pushed/popped pages.

Can you just try and change your code to be:

```
Application.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage(new UserPage());
```

This should create a NavigationPage wrapper around your userpage that will have the pre-built stack to use for popping and pushing to.

Comment: Yes it does. I edited my question. Sorry for being unclear. **EDIT** I may have misunderstood your statement.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should take a look if your app enter in

```
    protected override void OnResume()
```

or

```
    protected override void OnStart()
```

Can be that when you put your app in background, your app has been killed by OS so, when you reopen it, it start from the "Start", so from the "Login".

I think you can save a boolean flag in your

```
Application.Current.Properties
```

When your app starts, if this flag is true you start from UserPage, otherwise you Start from LoginPage

Comment: I logged them both, it indicates that the app starts over. Why is this happening? It is not preferred for the app to completely restart.

Comment: Sorry I have not understand... your app restart alway? you see alway "OnStart" and never "OnResume"?

Comment: It's strange that it restart every time it is in background. BTW, I have suggested to you, you can try to use a boolean flag. In OnStart you check this flag. If it's true (logged) you execute the UserPage, otherwise the LoginPage

Comment: I will use that boolean flag, I guess I don't have any other choice, however I'd like the app to behave in Android the same way it behaves in iOS. Is there really no other way to get it to sleep rather than restart?

Comment: I think it depends by SO... have another device (or an emulator) to test can be useful